# Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for class ABC

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "userLinkedPK")
@GenericGenerator(name = "userLinkedPK",
                  strategy = "foreign",
                  parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "user"))
@Column(name = "FKMEMBER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 5, scale = 0)
private Integer id;
```

> Error:- Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
> org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for

Changes:- Upgraded hibernate version from 5.3.10.Final to 5.4.24.Final

Can anyone suggest changes?

- Removed precision = 5, scale = 0, but no luck